# How can I keep a child label in place as a parent container is scrolled in WPF?

Tags: wpf, scroll

I am writing a timeline-style control. I want to keep the label in the same place while the item is scrolled until it gets to the end of that item. I made up a picture to show exactly what I am trying to do.

[image: "MDF" label stays put until it reaches the end of the control.]

Notice that as it is scrolled the "MDF" label stays put until it reaches the end of the control. I could spend the time to write my own, but I was wondering if there was a more straight forward way to do this using the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. This works, but if anyone can provide a simpler way of doing this, let me know.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CatalogEditor.MapItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="UserControl"
             d:DesignWidth="100" d:DesignHeight="75">
    <Border>
        <Grid x:Name="InnerBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Label/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MapItem.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MapItem : UserControl
{
    private ScrollViewer _scrollViewer = null;
    private double _maxMargin;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public MapItem()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
        InnerBox.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the size changes for this or the inner box element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _maxMargin = Math.Max(ActualWidth - InnerBox.ActualWidth, 0) - 5;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When this item is loaded into the visual tree.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);

        while (element != null && element is ScrollViewer == false)
            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

        var scrollViewer = element as ScrollViewer;

        if (scrollViewer == null)
            return;

        _scrollViewer = scrollViewer;
        _scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += OnScrollChanged;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the scroll viewer's scroll offset has changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rectangle = TransformToAncestor(_scrollViewer).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));

        var margin = Math.Min(_maxMargin, Math.Max(0, -rectangle.X));

        InnerBox.Margin = new Thickness(margin, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When this item is unloaded from the visual tree.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _scrollViewer.ScrollChanged -= OnScrollChanged;
        _scrollViewer = null;
    }

}
```